# How to play back to back mp3 in alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GB24XSZ/?tag=stackoverflow17-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GB24XSZ)

I want to play song one after one.
Now I am able to play one mp3 at a time, but I want to play 10 mp3 one after one.

```
PlayMusicIntent': function() {
        const songArr = data;
        const songIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songArr.length);
        const randomSong = songArr[songIndex];
        this.emit(':tell','Playing Laugh Music, <audio src=randomSong/>');
    }
```

Also Hi,
I have created my first alexa app but its not showing in Indian store. (amazon.in)
Any reason? Did I missed anything while uploading this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AudioPlayer` interface which provides directives and requests for streaming audio and monitoring playback progression. You have to enable this `Audio Player` interface in developer console.

More information on Audio Player [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html)

An example skill using
[nodejs-sdk-v1](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/releases/tag/sdkv1)
[nodejs-sdk-v2](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player)

Your skill Laugh Machine only supports `en-US`, English (US) locale.
Add `en-IN` English (IN) support, just configure the skill under English (IN) as you did for English (US). Both your locale can point to the same Lambda function if you want.

Comment: Hi, Are you able to run the app now?